# How to create HTML valid table with form inside rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create simple list in a form of table like on the image:
I am confused how to implement update/delete actions.
Both are `[HttpPost]` methods.
But I can't create forms inside `<td>` tags.
What is the valid way to make a table in the way that I want?

[image]

Comment: Why cant you create forms inside `<td>` tags?

Comment: As I understand that is not valid html then.

Comment: A form cannot be the child of a `table`, `tbody` or `tr` element. It can be the child of a `<td>` element.

Comment: So I shouldn't wrap 'tr' in form tags but I can wrap button inside t'd' right?

Comment: You can have a form inside a `td` element but it wont do you much good for the update button since the inputs are in other cells. You really need to use AJAX in this case to update and delete the rows.

Comment: What @StephenMuecke said... or you could also rethink your logic/flow. If you aren't using AJAX, then your form-post will cause a post-back... so having 20 forms on the page accomplishes nothing, since they can only use one at a time.

Comment: Yes I am using ajax here. So basicaly I have to get all elements from the first tr around clicked button and post them right?

Comment: I think so, but how are you doing this?
Are you using update panels? Are you "knockouting"? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have understood what do you need.
You can make one simple table and into each row put only one td which keep form.
Something like this:

```
<table>

@{
    foreach (var item in Model.MyCollection)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <table>
                        and hear put your existing row with your columns <tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

and you will have one form for each record.